# Get all url category with plagination from WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress

How to get all url category with plagination from WordPress ?

Example

```
http://sitename.com/category-name/
http://sitename.com/category-name/page/2/
http://sitename.com/category-name/page/3/

.....

http://sitename.com/category-name2/
http://sitename.com/category-name2/page/2/
http://sitename.com/category-name2/page/3/

.....
```

I searched very actively for an answer to this question, but did not find a solution at all. I hope very much for your help.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Pagination differs. If you know the total of posts and how many are per page then do the math ...  100 products / 10 per page = 10 pages .. or in your case http://sitename.com/category-name/page/9/ since we have 1st page as http://sitename.com/category-name